# Prevent rapid triggers of onClick listener

Tags: android

So I have a button with an associated OnClickListener. Every time the button is tapped I want to execute some code which sends a network request. However, if the user rapidly taps the button three times my code is executed three times. I'm trying to find a way where I can have some sort of time check where I only send my network request if, say, a second has passed without a subsequent tap.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this? The button is in a RecylerView item so the logic is implemented in a adapter.

Comment: Can you disable the button until the network request completes? Or ignore clicks until completion?

Comment: Good ideas but not sure how I would implement that as long as the onClickListener lives in the viewholder adapter.

Comment: Maybe you could ignore subsequent requests if one is already running

Answer (score 0):

You could save the millisecond from System millisecond function in a variable. Whenever it is clicked you can see whether it is long enough if it is, change the variable to the current. Otherwise, give a toast. Pseudocode example:

```
int millisecond = 0
onButtonClicked{

currentmilliseconds - milliseconds is less than given time in milliseconds, give toast
else, run network code & millisecond = current millisecond
}
```

Comment: Not sure how I could keep track of that as long as the OnClickListener lives in the adapter viewholder though.

Comment: if you are saying that you would get an error saying that it would have to be final, you could make it in the outside of oncreate like this:

Comment: int millisecond; public void onCreate()